# How to limit allowed time for a script run as a sub process in ksh script

Tags: ksh, ulimit

I try to limit the allowed of a sub process in a ksh script. I try using ulimit (hard or soft values) but the sub process always break the limit (if take longer than allowed time).

```
# value for a test
Sc_Timeout=2
Sc_FileOutRun=MyScript.log.Running
Sc_Cmd=./AScriptToRunInSubShell.sh

(
 ulimit -Ht ${Sc_Timeout}
 ulimit -St ${Sc_Timeout}

 time (
  ${Sc_Cmd} >> ${Sc_FileOutRun} 2>&1
  )  >> ${Sc_FileOutRun} 2>&1

  # some other command not relevant for this
 )
```

result:

```
1> ./MyScript.log.Running
ulimit -Ht 2
ulimit -St 2
1>> ./MyScript.log.Running 2>& 1

real    0m11.45s
user    0m3.33s
sys     0m4.12s
```

I expect a timeout error with a sys or user time of something like 0m2.00s

When i make a test directly from command line, the ulimit Hard seems to effectively limit the time bu not in script

System of test/dev is a AIX 6.1 but should also work other version and on sun and linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each process has its own time limits, but `time` shows the cumulative time for the script.   Each time you create a child process, that child will have its own limits.  So, for example, if you call `cut` and `grep` in the script then those processes use their own CPU time, the quota is not decremented from the script's, although the limits themselves are inherited.

If you want a time limit, you might wish to investigate `trap ALRM`.

Comment: tanks for info. I was thinkink the time was allowed for next process (so the use of subshell). I replace the ulimit by a catch of the process ID (started in background) with a sleep/kill watchdog